# Insert null values to postgresql timestamp data type using python

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I am tying to insert null value to a postgres timestamp datatype variable using python psycopg2.

The problem is the other data types such as char or int takes None, whereas the timestamp variable does not recognize None.

I tried to insert Null , null as a string because I am using a dictionary to get append the values for insert statement.

Below is the code.

```
queryDictOrdered[column] = queryDictOrdered[column] if isNull(queryDictOrdered[column]) is False else NULL
```

and the function is

```
def isNull(key):
    if str(key).lower() in ('null','n.a','none'):
        return True
    else:
        False
```

I get the below error messages:

> DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "NULL"
>   DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "None"

Answer (score 1):

Empty timestamps in Pandas dataframes come through as NaT (not a time), which is NOT pg compatible with NULL. A quick work around is to send it as a varchar and then run these 2 queries:

```
 update <<schema.table_name>> set <<column_name>> = Null where
 <<column_name>> = 'NULL';
```

or (depending on what you hard coded empty values as)

```
update <<schema.table_name>> set <<column_name>> = Null where <<column_name>> = 'NaT';
```

Finally run:

```
alter table <<schema.table_name>> 
alter COLUMN <<column_name>>  TYPE timestamp USING <<column_name>>::timestamp without time zone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you are adding quotes around the placeholder. Read psycopg documentation about passing parameters to queries.

Comment: the quotes around the null is to check the values before inserting !!! If you see the first piece of code I am trying to insert a NULL but since i am adding to a dictionary and then inserting the value I am not able to add NULL as a place holder but a string. So I need a work around to add null !!

Comment: use:
queryDictOrdered[column] = queryDictOrdered[column] if not isNull(queryDictOrdered[column]) else None

Comment: You can insert None to Varchar variables but unfortunately, you cannot insert None to postgressql datetime variable. That is where I am having issues. I have found a work around of inserting dummy dates eg: '9999-12-12' but still not sure of how to insert null value :(

Comment: You are wrong: you can insert NULL to any Postgres data type, including dates and timestamps, and you can do that passing a None in psycopg.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping this here incase it's helpful for anyone.

Using psycopg2 and the `cursor` object's `copy_from` method, you can copy missing or `NaT` datetime values from a pandas DataFrame to a Postgres `timestamp` field.

The `copy_from` method has a `null` parameter that is a "textual representation of `NULL` in the file. The default is the two characters string `\N`".  See [this link](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html) for more information.

Using pandas' `fillna` method, you can replace any missing datetime values with `\N` via `data["my_datetime_field"].fillna("\\N")`.  Notice the double backslash here, where the first backslash is necessary to escape the second backslash.

Using the `select_columns` method from the `pyjanitor` module (or `.loc[]` and some subsetting with the column names of your DataFrame), you can coerce multiple columns at once via something akin to this, where all of your datetime fields end with an `_at` suffix.

```
data_datetime_fields = \
    (data
     .select_columns("*_at")
     .apply(lambda x: x.fillna("\\N")))
```